# UML diagram does not show details in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml

I am using visual studio 2012 to produce UML diagram. Do like this: Architecture -> new diagram -> UML class diagram

But the produced class graph does not have connections with each other, and there is nothing inside each class, no attributes or operations, just a class name.
Actually the classes contain a lot of codes, and they do connect with each other.
Anyone knows why i got this simple graph?

[image]

Comment: How did you create the diagram? How did you add classes?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I do it in Architecture Explore. I think i know the reason,they are class folders, not the classes. probably i can not use folders directly

Comment: Yeah, _how_ did you add them? What did you drag?

Comment: @JohnSaunders First i click class view, then a list of namespace items shown in the right side, and i drag all items to above window, the picture is produced

Comment: Ok, that's it. You dragged the namespaces. You need to drag the classes.